# Rails 3 migration now fail in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I have this migration where I convert a column from integer to an array of string.

```
class ChangeWdayFromIntegerToStringInResourceWeekDayStart < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def up
    change_column :resource_week_day_starts, :wday, :string, default: []
    add_column :resource_week_day_starts, :number_days, :integer, default: 7
  end

  def down
    change_column :resource_week_day_starts, :wday, :string, default: nil
    change_column :resource_week_day_starts, :wday, 'integer USING CAST(wday AS integer)'
    remove_column :resource_week_day_starts, :number_days
  end
end
```

This migration works pretty well when we where in rails 3, but we have migrate to rails 5 and now we try to setup a new server. When running the migration in rails 5 we got this error message:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "wday" cannot be cast automatically to type character varying[]
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING wday::character varying[]".
: ALTER TABLE "resource_week_day_starts" ALTER COLUMN "wday" TYPE character varying[]
/home/ruby/src/mapsbooking/db/migrate/20170307000000_change_wday_from_integer_to_string_in_resource_week_day_start.rb:3:in `up'
```

I have try many ways to fix this up. But nothing works.

Can somebody help me

Thanks

Comment: I have try to add what they suggest in the error message, but I syntax error. I don't what is the good one.

Comment: If you want to declare resource_week_day_starts as a array (string datatype) column the migration should read `change_column :resource_week_day_starts, :wday, :string, array: true`

Comment: What type is the `wday` column now? An `integer`? And you want to change it to an array of strings (i.e. `varchar[]` or `character varying[]`)?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes it is an integer now and we want to convert to  character varying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. As [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) says in the comments, you need to include `array: true` in the options so that you get an array column.
2. You need an SQL expression to convert a single integer to an array of strings so that you can include a suitable USING clause in the ALTER TABLE.
3. `change_column` wants to change the type and the default separately.

**(1)** is easy, add `array: true` to the `change_column` options.

**(2)** is a little harder but a couple options come to mind. You could use the [element-to-array concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) and a type cast:

```
wday::varchar || array[]::varchar[]
```

`::` is a type cast, `||` is the concatenation operator, and `array[]` is an empty array. Or, if that's too much punctuation, you could use the [`array_append`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) function to do the same thing:

```
array_append(array[]::varchar[], wday::varchar)
```

**(3)** can be dealt with by dropping the old default with a [`change_column_default`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default) call before the `change_column`.

Putting them together:

```
change_column_default :resource_week_day_starts, :wday, nil
change_column :resource_week_day_starts,
              :wday,
              :string,
              array: true,
              default: [],
              using: 'array_append(array[]::varchar[], wday::varchar)'
```

This could leave you with `array[null]` values in `wday` if you currently have `nulls in`wday`. You can clean those up after if necessary.

Comment: seems it is not exactly the solution... on old server the column is of type: character varying DEFAULT '--- []'::character varying and on the news server it was of type character varying[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[] and I cannot import data from old  to new server.  How could i get character varaying instead on character varing[]

Comment: The `DEFAULT '--- []'::character varying` looks like some sort of YAML got into the column definition. `character varying[]` is an array of strings, `'{}'::character varying[]` is an empty array literal in PostgreSQL so that's all fine. I'm not sure what the problem is. You want to migrate to a single string rather than an array of strings? The old column wasn't actually an integer? You have weird data somewhere?

Comment: Yes in fact I want to have the exact same type of column in the new db. When the migration was created and run we were under rails 3, and the migration create a DEFAULT '--- []'::character varying. So I need to have my migration create a column exactly like if we were under rails 3. and yes the actuel content of the column is a sort of yml.

Comment: Why not set the default to `'--- []'` then? But really, if you're using PostgreSQL you'd be better off with real arrays rather than some `serialize` mess.